# Encountering error getting Spacy to load models

Tags: amazon-web-services, nlp, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, spacy

I've deployed a `Django` web app in `Elastic Beanstalk` and I'm trying to implement spacy, yet encountering errors.

I've listed the download link for the `en_core_web_sm` in my `requirements.txt` as `https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-1.2.0/en_core_web_sm-1.2.0.tar.gz`

I'm importing it in my code my calling `import en_core_web_sm` and later trying to load it with:

`nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()`

However in my logs from `eb` I'm getting errors indicating the model isn't loading properly. Am I missing something here? My instance is configured for `2gb` of RAM, that might not be enough, but it shouldn't effect the loading of the model, right? Why would it load the tokenizer but not the model?

```
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.276836 2017] [:error] [pid 23201] \x1b[93m    Warning: no model found for 'en'\x1b[0m
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.276841 2017] [:error] [pid 23201] 
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.276849 2017] [:error] [pid 23201] 
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.276851 2017] [:error] [pid 23201]     Only loading the 'en' tokenizer.
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.276855 2017] [:error] [pid 23201] 
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.333165 2017] [:error] [pid 23201] Internal Server Error: /webhookmb/
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.333187 2017] [:error] [pid 23201] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.333189 2017] [:error] [pid 23201]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.333192 2017] [:error] [pid 23201]     response = get_response(request)
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.333194 2017] [:error] [pid 23201]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.333196 2017] [:error] [pid 23201]     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.333198 2017] [:error] [pid 23201]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.333201 2017] [:error] [pid 23201]     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.333203 2017] [:error] [pid 23201]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.333205 2017] [:error] [pid 23201]     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.333216 2017] [:error] [pid 23201]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py", line 40, in inner
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.333218 2017] [:error] [pid 23201]     return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.333220 2017] [:error] [pid 23201]   File "/opt/python/current/app/webhookmb/views.py", line 81, in webhookmb
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.333222 2017] [:error] [pid 23201]     interpreter = Interpreter.load(metadata, RasaNLUConfig("rasa_nlu/config_spacy.json"))
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.333224 2017] [:error] [pid 23201]   File "/opt/python/current/app/rasa_nlu/model.py", line 213, in load
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.333226 2017] [:error] [pid 23201]     component_name, model_metadata.model_dir, model_metadata, **context)
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.333228 2017] [:error] [pid 23201]   File "/opt/python/current/app/rasa_nlu/components.py", line 310, in load_component
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.333229 2017] [:error] [pid 23201]     model_metadata, cached_component, **context)
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.333231 2017] [:error] [pid 23201]   File "/opt/python/current/app/rasa_nlu/registry.py", line 128, in load_component_by_name
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.333233 2017] [:error] [pid 23201]     return component_clz.load(model_dir, metadata, cached_component, **kwargs)
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.333235 2017] [:error] [pid 23201]   File "/opt/python/current/app/rasa_nlu/utils/spacy_utils.py", line 99, in load
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.333237 2017] [:error] [pid 23201]     cls.ensure_proper_language_model(nlp)
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.333239 2017] [:error] [pid 23201]   File "/opt/python/current/app/rasa_nlu/utils/spacy_utils.py", line 113, in ensure_proper_language_model
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.333240 2017] [:error] [pid 23201]     "Make sure you have downloaded the correct model (https://spacy.io/docs/usage/).")
[Fri Sep 01 04:33:49.333244 2017] [:error] [pid 23201] Exception: Failed to load spacy language model for lang 'en'. Make sure you have downloaded the correct model (https://spacy.io/docs/usage/).
```

Comment: did you download the english model?
something like:
python -m spacy download en

Comment: @lazary I resolved the issue by removing the link from requirement.txt and having the download run through the command line